# CSS/HTML Layout divs to fit in fixed-height div

Tags: css, html, height, width

I am new to CSS and I am trying to create something unusual.

My code:

```
<body>
<div style="background-color:#C1C1C1; height:100%;">
    <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div1
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div2
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div3
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div4
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div5
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div6
    </div>
        <div style="background-color:#F0F0F0; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; ">div7
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

let's say screen is 250px height -> the main div height will be 250px too then.

**Result:**

```
div1
div2
div3
...
```

I know that setting float:left; will display them like

```
div1 div2 div3 div4 div5 ....
```

**I would like to get:**

```
div1 div3 div5 div7
div2 div4 div6
```

It's like horizontal gallery.
Also, when there would be more divs, is it possible to make main div's width variable and add an x-scrollbar?

This is supposed to work on Internet Explorer 7 and higher only. Also, JavaScript is an option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Semantically you should be using a styled unordered list (UL LI) instead of DIVs.

Comment: Can you change the markup at all?

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? Is JavaScript and/or jQuery an option if it's absolutely required?

Comment: I need to support only Internet Explorer 7 and higher. JavaScript and jQuery can be included but I prefer it to be lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is quite easy with CSS3: http://jsfiddle.net/Ykkyg/

That fiddle provides the standard CSS for it, and the engine-specific properties for Webkit (Safari, Chrome) and Gecko (Firefox).

There's a couple of problems with this approach though:

- First, [IE doesn't support it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#multicolumn).
- Second, If that column set grows taller than the browser window, you're going to force your user to scroll up and down to read just one continuous piece of text. This sucks.

Without CSS3, you *can* achieve this effect by carefully sizing all elements a priori, but that doesn't scale, and I'm afraid I know of no generic solution to the problem that doesn't involve some non-trivial javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need it to work without CSS3 (yeah, I know CSS3 makes a lot of things much easier to do)